# Run React application in vm azure

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I want to run my react application on azure's virtual machine. I started my application in azure's vm but when I go to public url (DNS) of vm it says site can't be reached.

This is what I did to start my project in vm

1. I ran command ssh a********@52.***.**.***
2. After entering vm, I cloned the git project (React nodejs project)
3. I then install all the packages like npm, node and yarn, important to my project
4. I then ran gulp command. My project gets compiled successfully
5. Now, I tried accessing public url (DNS) of my azure's vm

**Expected Result**: I should be able to see my application page when DNS accessed

**Result**: Site cannot be reached

This is the serving part of my server file in project

```
const PORT = (process.env.PORT || 4200);
const runServer = (app)=> {
    app.listen(PORT, ()=> {
        debug(`Listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
        if (__DEV__)
            debug(`HMR on http://localhost:${config.BS_PORT}`);
    });
}


runServer(app);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I started my application in azure's vm but when I go to public url
>   (DNS) of vm it says site can't be reached.

Can you access this site with `localhost`? Please test it in your Azure VM, to make sure this service running in the correct port.

We should add port 4200 to Azure NSG (**Network security groups**) inbound rules.
We can follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-create-nsg-arm-pportal) to add port to NSG **inbound rules**.

By the way, if you are create a classic VM, we should follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/classic/setup-endpoints) to add port 4200 to VM's endpoints.

Also we should check **Linux firewall** settings, make sure the firewall will not block port 4200.

Finally, we can use `telnet` to test the network connection.

---

Update:

We can use `netstat -ant | grep 4200` to check the service is running or not.

For example, SSH service listen on port 22:

```
jason@jasonvm:~$ netstat -ant | grep 22
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0    104 10.0.0.4:22             167.220.255.8:57001     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:58122          52.239.153.36:443       TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:40922          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Also we can use `telnet` to test it, we can install telnet on your local PC, and run this command in CMD, like this `telnet vmpublicIP 4200`.

If your service listen on port 4200 and it run correctly, we can use this command to access it:
`curl localhost:4200`

Comment: I added port in networking tab of settings section. Still it's the same. Can you please check my added image in updates of question

Comment: can you try this command on your VM `curl localhost 4200`? Does that work?

Comment: It says this "Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused"

Comment: @ApurvG please run this command curl localhost:4200. And netstat-ant | grep 4200

Comment: @ApurvG please install netstat tool on it and test again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156906/discussion-between-apurvg-and-jason-ye-msft).

Comment: @ApurvG For now, can you browse your application? please let me know if you need more help:)

Comment: Yes I can brows now. I was doing nodemon --inspect. And that was the culprit. Removed that and it worked